# Поисковик по пользователям

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

На сайте имеются пользователя, пытаюсь сделать поисковик по пользователям, чтоб нашел по имени, фамилии, городу и чтобы выводил ссылкой на страницы, а данный код у меня не работает, не находит, БД подключена.

```
   <?
     function search ($query) 
  { 
$query = trim($query); 
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
$query = htmlspecialchars($query);

if (!empty($query)) 
{ 
    if (strlen($query) < 3) {
        $text = '<p>Слишком короткий поисковый запрос.</p>';
    } else if (strlen($query) > 128) {
        $text = '<p>Слишком длинный поисковый запрос.</p>';
    } else { 
        $q = "SELECT `surname`, `name`, `city`, `id`
              FROM `users` WHERE `text` LIKE '%$query%'
              OR `name` LIKE '%$query%' OR `surname` LIKE '%$query%'
              OR `meta_d` LIKE '%$query%'";

        $result = mysql_query($q);

        if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
            $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

            $text = '<p>По запросу <b>'.$query.'</b> найдено совпадений: '.$num.'</p>';

            do {
                // Делаем запрос, получающий ссылки на статьи
                $q1 = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$row[page_id]'";
                $result1 = mysql_query($q1);

                if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
                    $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
                }

                $text .= '<p><a> href="'.$row1['link'].'/'.$row['category'].'/'.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['title_link'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a></p>
                <p>'.$row['desc'].'</p>';

            } while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); 
        } else {
            $text = '<p>По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.</p>';
        }
    } 
} else {
    $text = '<p>Задан пустой поисковый запрос.</p>';
}

return $text;
```

} 
?>

Answer (score 1):

Одна из важных техник, которую в программировании необходимо осваивать с самого начала - это декомпозиция, разбиение задачи на подзадачи. Обычно задача разбивается не на самые мелкие подзадачи, а на функциональные блоки, которые, в свою очередь, также могут разбиваться, и так хоть до бесконечности.

Декомпозиция позволяет выделить эти функциональные блоки, обернуть их в функции и вынести из основного кода. Именно так получается, что мы работаем со строками и не вынуждены напрямую дергать процессор, чтобы получить какое-то значение (если только не пишем на ассемблере) - мы работаем со строковыми функциями.

Конкретно вашу задачу можно разбить так:

- Поиск пользователя

  - Валидация поисковой строки

    - Проверка на пустоту
    - Проверка на слишком маленькую длину
    - Проверка на слишком большую длину
  - Поиск в базе данных

    - Подключение к базе данных
    - Выполнение запроса
    - Получение результата
    - Закрытие подключения
  - Вывод результата

    - Вывод лейаута (общего стиля сайта)
    - Вывод шаблона страницы поиска
    - Вывод данных или сообщения валидации

Все это (почти все) сейчас реализуется в одной функции, что увеличивает связность кода, препятствует рефакторингу и еще много умных слов - все это в результате дает а) необходимость править функцию поиска при любой правке шаблона / запроса поиска / правил валидации, б) уменьшение концентрации (я не шучу) - при работе с этой функцией приходится отвлекаться на те вещи, которые не имеют отношения к текущим правкам, в) потерю времени, когда таких функций становится много, и поиск местанахождения того или иного куска кода становится проблемой, г) проблемы с отладкой из-за недостаточной изолированности (предположим, что mysql багнулась и не выполняет почему-то запрос - перейти на другой движок будет сложно).

Что будет, если разбить эту большую функцию на много мелких? Она будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
function actionSearch($query)
{
    // Пускай validate_search_query возвращает true, если все окей, и массив ошибок, если окей не все
    $validationResult = validate_search_query($query);
    if ($validationResult !== true) {
        $data = array('errors' => $validationResult);
    } else {
        // Пускай возвращает или массив ['errors' => []] или ['users' => []]
        $data = find_users_by_query($query);
    }
    // Запускаем рендеринг шаблона с полученными данными, будь то ошибки или нужные данные. Шаблон уже сам разберется об удачности или неудаче поиска по наличию элемента 'errors' в массиве.
    render('search', $data);
}
```

*(на самом деле в процедурном программировании сведения об ошибках будут доставаться немного иначе, но для примера сойдет)*

Если привести функцию к такому виду, то при наличии проблем с поиском можно будет копать не ее всю, а непосредственно `find_users_by_query()`, смотреть на ее вывод и не задумываться ни о че остальном.

Теперь что до существующей функции:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
...
do {
    ...
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

это очень жесткий антипаттерн. Во-первых, человек, глядящий на `do .. while` не понимает, как цикл выполняется в первый раз (ведь `$row` появится только тогда, когда цикл дойдет до `while`), во-вторых, никто не гарантирует, что мускуль вернул данные вообще, и

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

имеет полное право не сработать, если нашлось ноль строк.

Реальная же проблема, насколько понимаю, кроется в этой строчке:

```
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
```

affected rows - это количество *измененных* строк, т.е. количество *добавленных, обновленных* или *удаленных* строк; в этом запросе таких нет, поэтому результат этой функции будет продолжать возвращать вам ноль, и условия не будет выполняться. Вам нужна `mysql_num_rows()`, которая зачем-то лежимт чуть ниже.

Эта строка:

```
$q1 = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$row[page_id]'";
```

не имеет никакого смысла, так как выбирает, по факту, `$row['page_id']`. Это имело бы смысл для проверки существования пользователя, но т.к. эти данные получены от движка БД, он уже гарантированно существует.

Если переписывать критическую часть функции, то она будет выглядеть так:

```
$result = mysql_query($q);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($numRows > 0) { 
    $text = "<p>По запросу <b>$query</b> найдено $numRows совпадений.</p>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $text .= '<p>';
        $text .= '<a href="/users.php?id='.$row['id'].'">';
        $text .= $row['name'].' '.$row['surname'];
        $text .= '</a>';
        $text .= '</p>';
    }
} else {
    $text = '<p>По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.</p>';
}
```

p.s. c индентацией в этот раз гораздо лучше